# How to get the product image with custom size?

Tags: php-7, magento2.2.4

How to get product image with custom size for api in magento2.2.4

```
   use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory;
$imageCode = 'upsell_products_list';
    $imageHelper = $this->_imageFactory->create()->init($product, $imageCode)->getUrl();
```

I tried above code .But i can't get  the correct image url..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$objectManager =\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imghelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$imageUrl = $imghelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                ->setImageFile($product->getImage())
                ->resize(400)
                ->getUrl();
```

Obviously you should avoid the objectmanager and inject instead.

See `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php` `public function getGalleryImages()` in line 55